# Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query. (ORA-00905: missing keyword)

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-apex

Trying to create an interactive report with the below sql query. getting error mentioned in title.

```
SELECT 
  FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME "USERNAME" 
FROM 
  USERS 
WHERE 
  USERNAME IN (
    select 
      username 
    from 
      users 
    where 
      username not in (
        Select 
          accessed_by 
        from 
          temp_amal
        where 
          access_date >= :P2610_DATE_FROM
          and access_date <= :P2610_DATE_TO
          and (CASE :P2610_RADIO
            when 'F' then col1='F'
          end)
      )
  )
order by 1;
```

Comment: It would seem that you're missing a keyword. Please look through it very carefully and see if you can find it.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` condition's both operands *cannot* be in a `CASE`. Just either one of them.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME "USERNAME" FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME 
IN
(select username from users 
where username not in 
(Select accessed_by from temp_amal
where access_date >= :P2610_DATE_FROM
and access_date <= :P2610_DATE_TO
and col1 = (CASE :P2610_RADIO
            when 'F' then 'F'
            end)
))
order by 1;
```

So, if you want to make your query more dynamic. You have to for dynamic SQL query generation.